# Win 2008 Group Policy : Does Drive Maps (GPP) run before Logon Script setting? Both user configs are set within same policy

Tags: windows-server-2008, mappeddrive, logon-scripts, group-policy

I'm on Win 2008 R2 DC with XP and Win7 desktops.
On one of User GPOs, there is Drive Maps and Logon Script configured.
Drive Maps are under GPP, and Logon Script is under user config.
Both user configs are set under one group policy.

How can I ensure Logon Script runs after Drive Maps?

EDIt : There is same/similar question that has much more detailed answers.  [What is the order group policy settings are applied?](https://serverfault.com/questions/52370/what-is-the-order-group-policy-settings-are-applied)  But it doesnt really answer my question.  Comments below by ChrisS answers my question concisely.

Comment: Mapping drives are Group Policy Preferences (unless they're a script) and come before Logon Scripts.

Comment: @ChrisS - I could see that it's basically the same question but answers provide much more than what I asked for, and in different context (eg. providing how multiple GPOs gets processed, etc)  I just wanted concise answer like you've mentioned in the comment.  I rather put your comment as the answer to my question, and I think it'll be helpful for someone that just wants to know if GPP configs get processed before GPO within the same user policy.

Comment: Most of the order stuff is ungodly messy, you just happened upon an exception that Login Scripts are run after everything else (for historical reasons no less).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User policy is applied before logon scripts. If you wanted to "fool proof" it you could always put a check in your logon script for the mapped drives.

> User policy is applied. These are the settings under User Configuration from the gathered list. GPOs are processed in the following order: local, site, domain, organizational unit, child organizational unit, and so on. No notification appears while user policies are processed. (Notification can be turned on through policy.)
>
> Logon scripts run. Unlike Windows NT 4.0 scripts, Group Policy–based logon scripts are hidden and asynchronous by default. The user object script runs last in a normal window. There is also a time-out on logon scripts.

[Source](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc785665%28WS.10,loband%29.aspx#Order_of_processing_settings)